# PHP if statement is breaking the layout - adding big space

Tags: php, html, css, if-statement

I have this table working normally, and when I add an if statement (so that if you are not the author of the post you cannot edit or delete it) suddenly there is a big white space. It´s an if statement just including the 2 last columns (Edit, and Delete). Why could it be breaking?

[image: Image here: Big space between controllers and table]

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['username'] == $post_author) { ?>

<td><a href="posts.php?source=edit_post&post_id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Edit</a></td>
<td><a onclick="javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this post?');" href="posts.php?delete=<?php echo $id; ?>">Delete</a></td>

<?php  }else{ echo "<td></td></br><td></td>";} ?>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: why is there a `</br>` in `<td></td></br><td></td>`

Comment: `<br />` not `</br>`

Comment: Exactly, the </br> is useless. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `</br>` tag. You can use `nbsp;` instead of `</br>`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved it. Actually I had to type &nbsp, right? 

And actually, just removing </br> solved it. I dont know why I put it there. Beginners nonsense. :)